# Load Comments for specific posts from Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a Post class, which is a collection of all the posts. Each post has associated comments. I am using a `PFQueryTableViewController` to load the posts in one view, and a `PFQueryTableViewController` to load the comments for a specific post in the next.

The Posts all load correctly into the first `PFQueryTableViewController`. What I can't figure out is how to efficiently load the comments that correspond to specific posts.

My current strategy is this: in the Post's tableViewController, in prepareForSegue, pass the objectId of the specific post that is clicked on. I use the following code:

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let nextViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondTableViewController

    var row = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row
    let nameToPass = idArray[row!]
    nextViewController.nameToPass = idArray[row!]



   }
```

But I'm not really sure where to go from there. Here is the code for my Comments class, the `PFObject` class:

```
  import UIKit
  import ParseUI
  import Parse
  import Foundation

  class Comments: PFObject, PFSubclassing {
@NSManaged var image: PFFile


@NSManaged var short_decription: String?

@NSManaged var nameToGet: String?

//1
class func parseClassName() -> String {
    return "Comments"
}

//2
override class func initialize() {
    var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
    dispatch_once(&onceToken) {
        self.registerSubclass()
    }
}

override class func query() -> PFQuery? {
    println("name to get is next")

    let query = PFQuery(className: Comments.parseClassName())
    //query.whereKey("to_post", equalTo: <individual Post object here>)
    query.includeKey("from_user")
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    return query
}

init(short_decription: String?) {
    super.init()


}

override init() {
    super.init()



     }

  }
```

This line is the what I need to fix:

```
    //query.whereKey("to_post", equalTo: <individual Post object here>)
```

How can I get the individual Post object into there? I think it's possible some way, given that I can pass the objectId of the Post I want to get to the `SecondTableviewController` (the `PFQueryTableViewController` that loads the comments), but just not sure how. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the query work you need to use the very PFObject you are looking for as the "equalTo" parameter.

I.e.

```
query.whereKey("to_post", equalTo: myObject)
```

You just need to pass the post's PFObject during the segue, instead of its ID.

Note: This is all assuming the "to_post" column is a POINTER to the post class.

Comment: i know that's what I need to do,, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: You have an array of ids (idArray) which you stored when you queried for the posts. Instead of storing just the ids, you need to store the PFObject itself, that way you can pass it during the seque, then include the predicate in the query and get the post's comments/

Answer (score 0):

You can call class `Comments` method to get query by passing objectId of `Post`.  Like this:

```
class func query(postObjectId: String) -> PFQuery? {
    println("name to get is next")

    let query = PFQuery(className: Comments.parseClassName())
    //query.whereKey("to_post", equalTo: <individual Post object here>)
    query.includeKey("from_user")
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    return query
}
```

You can create parse object from objectId and pass it.

Comment: I understand that using the object Id, I can call getObjectinBackgroundWithId, and then pass in the ID and get the object. But I can't get the object Id from the tableviewcontroller to the Comments class. The comments class conforms to PFObject, not NSObject, so I can't pass a string into the class via prepareForSegue.